# Jquery Templates doesn't show up in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

I was trying to use the jquery templates (http://stanlemon.net/projects/jquery-templates.html).

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to fetch an array of objects through JSON and render them using the jquery templates. I get the JSON as follows

```
[{"type":"todo","title":"sample task","description":"this is description","tags":["todo","delete"],"objectId":"2"},{"type":"todo","title":"Do it right now","description":"you have to do everything","tags":["todo","delete"],"objectId":"3"}]
```

And to render it using the jquery template plugin, I do the following

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
  var task = data[i];
  //alert('hello');
  $('#tasks').append($.template(taskTemplate), task);
}
```

**What happens**

This works fine in firefox and chrome but not in IE (I have v8). The for loop is executed but nothing is rendered in the #tasks div. The weird thing I noticed is that if I uncomment the alert in for loop, things are rendered properly after every pop up.

What could be the problem? please help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does IE8 show any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: No, it does not show any error. It behaves as if everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same issue. My problem was to remove an empty div tag with a clear class. try removing elements one by one until the markup is shown. Worked for me.

I see [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) are staying in beta for the time being. You may want to move to [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) or [handlebarsjs](http://handlebarsjs.com/) js templates that as of 14/04/2012 has active support.

Perhaps not the technical answer you were looking for but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a bug in the original [jquery templates](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js):

just save the file and edit it:

at line 428 replace

```
pntItem && pntItem.key != pntNode
```

with

```
pntItem != undefined && pntItem.nodes != undefined && pntItem.key != pntNode
```

That worked for me (Tested with IE9: IE9 was giving me an error at that exact line in my script)